# How to add NOCHECK to MSSMS when adding relationship between two tables?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add a relationship between 2 tables, but i am getting the "The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" error.

This is because there is some data in one of the tables that doesnt match the data in the other table.

I want to add the NOCHECK option, so that it wont check if the data is accurate. How can i do this using MSSMS?

Example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Column_Definition SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tabelform_Answers ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_Tabelform_Answers_Column_Definition FOREIGN KEY
    (
    column_id
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Column_Definition
    (
    id
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tabelform_Answers SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your query:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tabelform_Answers WITH NOCHECK
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Tabelform_Answers_Column_Definition
   FOREIGN KEY ( column_id )
   REFERENCES dbo.Column_Definition ( id )
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Reference to MSDN article on [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Comment: Where can i type this, because i am using the GUI to add the relationship. I can generate a change script and edit it, but where can i paste and execute it?

Comment: Can you check my updated question, and tell me where to put NOCHECK? Because i am getting a syntax error everywhere i put it.